# Not able to connect database to llamaindex DatabaseReader

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model, llama-index

Hi want to connect my database to directly load data from database and shows this error wen i run this code . ive installed everything but still showing this error.

```
from llama_index.core  import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
import pickle
import openai
from llama_index.readers.database import DatabaseReader
openai.api_key = 'OPENAI_API_KEY'


db  = DatabaseReader(
     scheme="mysql",  # Database Scheme
    host="localhost",  # Database Host
    port="3306",  # Database Port
    user="8888888",  # Database User
    password="88888888",  # Database Password
    dbname="(******)",  # Database Name
)
print(type(db))

print(type(db.load_data))
```

```
  File "/home/admin/web/kiarxcloudapi.in/public_html/kiarxai/load_data_new.py", line 11
    from __future__ import absolute_import
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file
# /usr/bin/python3 /home/admin/web/kiarxcloudapi.in/public_html/kiarxai/load_data_new.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/web/kiarxcloudapi.in/public_html/kiarxai/load_data_new.py", line 16, in <module>
    db  = DatabaseReader(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/readers/database/base.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.sql_database = SQLDatabase.from_uri(uri, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/core/utilities/sql_wrapper.py", line 133, in from_uri
    return cls(create_engine(database_uri, **_engine_args), **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 599, in create_engine
    dbapi = dbapi_meth(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 152, in import_dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I want it to connect to database . LLamaindex databse reader